# Local Shared Object localPath

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shared-objects, local-shared-object

I'm creating an .swf movie that will store a Local Shared Object on the visitors' machines of a community.

Basically, the .swf movie is part of an add-on for forum communities. By that I mean that I don't know beforehand the full path of the .swf movie.

I.e. one may have his community in:

www.domain1.com/forum
OR
www.domain2.com/forums
OR
www.domain3.com/community

etc... In any case, the .swf movie will be in www.domainX.com/{some unknown folder}/{known1}/{known2}/movie.swf

I hope you understand everything so far.

My problem is what argument to use as the localPath of the getLocal method to store the LSO.

What I do so far is this: SharedObject.getLocal("guid", "/");

which creates a guid.sol file in #SharedObjects\X9X9X9X9\www.domain1.com

If I do it like this: SharedObject.getLocal("guid"); (which is, totally omitting the localPath arguement, thus it'll use the full path), it will create a guid.sol file in #SharedObjects\X9X9X9X9\www.domain1.com\community\public\cache

So, without knowing the folder name the community will reside in, how can I store the LSO two folders before the full path?

As in: #SharedObjects\X9X9X9X9\www.domain1.com\community
OR #SharedObjects\X9X9X9X9\www.domain1.com\forum OR #SharedObjects\X9X9X9X9\www.domain1.com\whatever

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found this...

```
urlArr = _root._url.split("/");
pathLso = urlArr[urlArr.length - 3]; //As I wanted the 3rd from the end chunk
lsoObj = SharedObject.getLocal("guid", pathLso);
```